# Can Emacs run command in background

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have an Emacs command like following:

```
(defun query-lisp (word)
  (interactive "sType a word to query:")
  (message "%s" (query word)))
```

The `query` operation is a time-consuming operation. When this command is running Emacs blocks the whole frame. Is there a way to make Emacs run this command in the background or block only a single window such as the minibuffer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Emacs doesn't have threads. For long operations you can split up the task into chunks and execute the chunks in [idle timers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Idle-Timers.html#Idle-Timers), so emacs can respond to user input between the chunks.

The other possibility is running it as an external process from which emacs accepts the output.

Comment: +1 for the infomation.Actually the query function I wrote is in python and load to emacs by pymacs,So I think external process maybe a solution, Can you detail more about how external process interactive with emacs?

Comment: The [relevant part of the emacs lisp manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Processes.html) explains everything in great detail with examples.

Comment: But if you only want to execute an external command and display its output then you can get by using [the built in commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual//html_node/emacs/Shell.html).

Answer (score 11):

If you plan to use an external process (which you have indicated in a comment to another question), you can use the following:

```
 (start-process NAME BUFFER PROGRAM &rest PROGRAM-ARGS)
```

This will return a *process* object. You can either send the output to a buffer, or you could attach a *filter function* to the process. In the latter case, this is a function that is called every time your process emits any output.

In addition, you could attach a *sentinel function* to your process. This function is called everytime the status of your process changes, this is useful to find out when it has exited.

There are several examples of the above in the source code of Emacs, one such example is `compile.el`.

Answer (score 4):

For example, you can use something like this

```
(shell-command "sleep 10 && echo 'finished' &")
```

The result will be displayed in `*Async Shell Command*` buffer.

Comment: The nice thing about `shell-command` and `async-shell-command` (the latter of which is equivalent to `(shell-command "... &")`) is that they can be called interactively and they are bound to `M-!` and `M-&` respectively.